# Apply the font type used on webpage

Tags: html, css, fonts

There are many variations of this font used for the London Street Sign, however my client has fallen in love with this particular one on the following site:
http://www.myfunstudio.com/designs/lss/

So tried running the site from a FONT ANALYZER site, which has yielded good results in the past. However this time unfortunately I remained at square one.
http://website-font-analyzer.com/myfunstudio.com/designs/lss/.html 
As the site informed me the font was called “StreetSign”.  However this isn’t correct, I suspect the CSS has been written to show this as the font name.

Next I went to the site typed in a custom street name (bohemian rhapsody). saved it as an HTML file, and opened it in Dreamweaver.

In design mode I was able to openly use the font within Dreamweaver - however this time the name of the font type showed up as ‘. ‘

Toggling into HTML mode, I searched through the file to look for the custom street name and found the following line:

```
<p class="p39"><span class="s23">PU</span><span class="s13">bohemian rhapsody</span></p>
```

Then searched through the CSS header to find this for class p39.

```
p.p39 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; line-height: 189.0px; font: 189.0px '.'; color: #000000; -webkit-text-stroke: #000000}
```

The font seems to be labeled as dot space, which I don’t know what’s going on here, or perhaps I’ve missed something obvious?  I’ve done extensive googling on the internet in regards to extracting fonts from websites, however normally the names are just either simply listed if they’re using google, or other font webkits.

The font must already be downloaded onto my Mac (also checked Font Book wasn’t there) if i’m able to openly use it in Dreamweaver, however i need to be able to openly use it in my design suite.

I’m really unsure how to achieve this, and am very open to possible suggestions on proceeding forward.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's personalized font. It's name 'KeepCalmAndTypeOn'.
If you'll check sources in debugger, you'll find:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'KeepCalmWebOnly';
    src: url('../webfonts/keepcalmandtypeon-webonly.eot');
    src: url('../webfonts/keepcalmandtypeon-webonly.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../webfonts/keepcalmandtypeon-webonly.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../webfonts/keepcalmandtypeon-webonly.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Though you can easily download and use font files, I would recommend to connect with Marijn Kamp, as he's copyright owner (Name extracted from font info).